# Is it possible to change the black colour of CKEditor Toolbar icons(in the moono skin), like one can with webfonts.?

Tags: ckeditor

I have just upgraded to CKEditor 4.4.5 from 3.5, and notice quite a few changes !! One of the changes is the new skin called Moono which looks great. However it did get me wondering whether it would be possible to change the black in the menu icons to a custom colour, for branding reasons for example. We do this in the rest of the web application using a combination of Server code and CSS.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Toolbar icons in Moono are images, so if you want to change them, you'd need to create a new skin or use an alternative one from the [CKEditor Addons Repository](http://ckeditor.com/addons/skins/all).

However, since Moono is a monochromatic skin, maybe for branding purposes it would be enough for you to use the so-called "[chameleon feature](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/skin_sdk_chameleon)" that lets you change the UI color with a simple configuration option?

If so, just use [`config.uiColor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-uiColor) to provide a mataching RGB color value or an HTML color name, as in:

```
config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
```

See a working example here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/uicolor.html